# How to listen the riverpod with family

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I have this provider with family

```
final gameControllerProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose
    .family<GameController, GameLevel>((ref, gameLevel) {
  final gameController = GameController()..initializeController(gameLevel, ref);

  return gameController;
});
```

To watch this we have to pass a parameter in provider something like this:

```
final controller = ref.watch(gameControllerProvider(gameLevel));
```

now if we have to listen this provider we have to do something like this

```
 ref.listen<GameController>(gameControllerProvider(gameLevel), ((previous, next) {
     ....
    }));
```

Now, I think that every we pass a parameter in our provider, it will create an another instance of object. The question of this is that does my **controller** and ref.listen(provider) is pointed to the same instance? or not?

View this photo as a visualize:
[image]

Comment: What type is GameLevel?  Does it have a working ==?

Comment: A class extends ChangeNotitifier class

Comment: How are you using instances of that as family keys?